# visual studio 10 inserting &nbsp into select list

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a select list with some option values inside an asp.net tablecell.  For some reason VS10 keeps placing more and more non breaking spaces into the code before the option values.  I have to keep deleting them because it eventually fills the page with them.  Here is my original code:

```
        <asp:TableCell>
            <select id="selectBankID" onchange="changeFormatLabel(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'txtBankIDFormat')">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="SWIFT (W/Branch)">SWIFT (W/Branch)</option>
                <option value="SWIFT (W/O Branch)">SWIFT (W/O Branch)</option>
                <option value="BSB">BSB</option>
                <option value="BIC">BIC</option>
                <option value="TRNO">TRNO</option>
                <option value="BLZ">BLZ</option>
                <option value="UKSORT">UKSORT</option>
            </select>
        </asp:TableCell>
```

On its own, without my saving or anything, a bunch of nbsp characters appear out of nowhere and just keep multiplying as I keep working on other parts of the page:

```
        <asp:TableCell>
            <select id="selectIntermedBankID" onchange="changeFormatLabel(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'txtIntermedBankIDFormat')">
```

SWIFT (W/Branch)

SWIFT (W/O Branch)

BSB

BIC

TRNO

BLZ

UKSORT

Of course, they don't display nicely in the code window on this site, but they are there.  What the #@$!* is going on?  Visual Studio hatred for non asp tags?

Comment: Screw it.  I just changed the select to an asp dropdownlist and added the 'onchange' parameter to the tag in the code behind so I can still get the javascript to run.  No more rogue inserts of a bunch of useless characters.  Whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, just used a dropdownlist instead of standard HTML selectlist.

Answer (score 0):

Friends there is a simple solution for this...
Remove all spaces and carriage returns with in the control. Problem will be solved

for eg: if your control is like

```
<Select>
 <Option>1</Option>
 <Option>2</Option>
</Select>
```

Solution is to make the mark up as following
"12"

Let me know whether you are still facing this issue